# Why does appear "[sudo]" after sudo commands?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sudo

After installation openssh-server I see [sudo] after run sudo command from terminal.
After I removed openssh-server, I still see it.
What does it mean?
And how I remove it ?

Example:

> username:~$ sudo ls

> **[sudo]** password for username:

Ubuntu 20.04

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That is part of the default `sudo prompt on Ubuntu`.  It is configurable in the `sudoers` file, on the command line, or via the `SUDO_PROMPT` environment variable.

For example, if you want to make the prompt be "`password for username:` ", add the following to your `/etc/sudoers` file using visudo.

> Defaults passprompt = "password for %p: "

For a traditional Unix password prompt, try:

> Defaults passprompt = "Password: "

You can also set the prompt using `sudo's -p` flag or by setting the `SUDO_PROMPT` environment variable in your shell startup files (.profile, .bashrc, etc) if you'd rather.